# Error while using pytesseract.image_to_string

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-tesseract

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image 
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR"
w1 = cv2.imread('Downloads\ocr4.png')
plt.imshow(w1)
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
plt.show()

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(w1)
print(text)
```

'''
**its showing this error**

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
255     except OSError as e:
256         if e.errno != ENOENT:
--> 257             raise e
258         raise TesseractNotFoundError()
259

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
252
253     try:
--> 254         proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
255     except OSError as e:
256         if e.errno != ENOENT:

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in **init**(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask)
949                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
950
--> 951             self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
952                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
953                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

~\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid, unused_umask, unused_start_new_session)
1418             # Start the process
1419             try:
-> 1420                 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
1421                                          # no special security
1422                                          None, None,

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
'''

Answer (score 0):

The path included was incorrect...
It's working now:)
Hope this might help others with the same error.